# The Pagination will fixed in the bottom I want to show the pagination after the last row shown in table. I use react-data-table-component

Tags: reactjs, react-data-table-component

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUWbj.png)Explanation: The Pagination will fixed in the bottom I want to show the pagination after the last row shown in table. I use react-data-table-component

```
<DataTable
   fixedHeader={true}
   fixedHeaderScrollHeight="70vh"
   noHeader
   pagination
   sortServer
   paginationServer
   keyField={(row, index) => index}
   subHeader={true}
   columns={
       props.quickAdd
        ? quickColumns(ability, defaultCurrency)
        : hidden
           ? type === "0"
           ? comColumns(ability, defaultCurrency.symbol, filterList, PackingSlip, handleRowClick, handleReceiving, handleVoidInvoice, handleDeleteInvoice, defaultCurrency, openPaymentsPopOvers, setOpenPopOvers)
           : columns(ability, defaultCurrency.symbol, filterList, PackingSlip, handleRowClick, handleReceiving, handleVoidInvoice)
            : collapseColumns(ability, defaultCurrency.symbol, filterList, handleRowClick, true)
   }
   responsive={true}
   // onSort={handleSort}
   data={hidden ? (type === "0" ? store.consolidated : store.data) : store.consolidated}
   sortIcon={<ChevronDown />}
   className="react-dataTable"
   defaultSortField="sno"
   paginationDefaultPage={currentPage}
   paginationComponent={CustomPagination}
   subHeaderComponent={<CustomHeader toggleSearchBar={toggleSearchBar} rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage} handlePerPage={handlePerPage} type={type} handleType={handleType} />}
/>
```